# Node.js/Express: async function inside middleware?

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

I was wondering how you make async functions to work inside *middleware*? Normally `await` in front of the function would get the job done, but in *middleware* it seems not working.

**index.js:**

```
const bob= require('../middleware/bob');
router.get('/', [bob(['channel1','channel2','channel3'])], async (req, res) => {
    console.log('3')
})
```

**middleware/bob.js:**

```
async function test(){
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('1')
    }, 2000);
}

module.exports = function(channels){
   return async(req, res, next) =>{
        await test();
        console.log('2')

        next();
    }
}
```

When I run this code. It will write into console: 2 3 1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`await` awaits for a promise. A promise that is returned from `test` function is resolved immediately. `async` function shouldn't be aware of `setTimeout` of any asynchronous processes that happen inside of it except promises that are chained with `await` or `return`.

If the intention is to delay it, it should be:

```
async function test(){
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));
    console.log('1')
}
```